# PHP Add TimeFormats to return DateTime

Tags: php, datetime, time

I am trying to add 2 different time formats.

the first formatted in the **m/d/Y** format, **12/3/2014** and the second in the form of **4:30 PM H:i A**, I am using the following code to add the two together,

```
$time1= "12/3/2014";
$time2= "4:30 PM";

$insert_date=date("l, F j, Y, g:i A",strtotime($time1)+strtotime($time2))."\n";

echo $insert_date; //for debugging
```

The end result of this would be inserted into a mysql database field of the type DateTime.

This however does not yield the correct result which should be 
**Wednesday, December 3, 2014, 4:30 PM**, it produces a date which is far in the future.

I am hoping it might be something simple that I am missing, thanks in advance.

Comment: You are adding (`+`) two timestamps together. Concatenate the strings first then run `strtotime` on it. ie `$fulltime = strtotime($time1.' '.$time2);`

Answer (score 4):

You need to concatenate your dates, not add them together:

```
$insert_date=date("l, F j, Y, g:i A",strtotime($time1 . ' ' . $time2))."\n";
```

I'm not entirely sure that date format will work with `strtotime()` so maybe using [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) might be a better idea:

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/n/Y g:i A', $time1 . ' ' . $time2);
$insert_date = datetime->format(l, F j, Y, g:i A);
```

FYI, storing your dates as strings, especially in non-standard formats, is not recommended and can make your life difficult in the future if you ever need to do date math with them.

Comment: I realized shortly after I posted my question that I forgot to include the code to insert the information into the database, in that code I convert from the format I wanted originally to the format used by the DateTime type in the MYSQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the time variables(with a '.'). You are adding them (with the '+') in your code.

```
<?php
$time1= "12/3/2014"; 
$time2= "4:30 PM";

$insert_date=date("l, F j, Y, g:i A",strtotime($time1.$time2))."\n";

echo $insert_date; //for debugging

?>
```

Also, you may want to save the result as a unix timestamp for better queries and standardization. Then format the timestamp however you want when you get them from the DB.

```
$insert_date=strtotime($time1.$time2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me.

```
$combined_time=date("l, F j, Y, g:i A",strtotime($row["Date"].$row["Begin Time"]));

//print combined time to the page.
echo $combined_time;


//convert the combined time to be compatible with DateTime.
$this->event->date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($combined_time));
if($this->event->insert()){

echo "Event Saved Successfully!".;

}
```

If anyone spots any potential problems with this solution please let me know. And thanks for everyone's help.